# In Html page <input type=range value=5> shows the scroller at 5, but the value field should read a file and print the value which is inside file

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up an HTML page for a policy which should read the values of the parameters from the policy page and display it in the browser. Right now I have written a shell script to read and display the value for the parameter I provide.
Now my question is, is it possible to put the same script under "`input type=range value='./script'`" or do you have any other option to read form the config/policy file.

```js
function resetFunc() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

function checkLength1(elem) {
  if (elem.value > 100) {
    alert('Max value is 100')
    elem.value = '';
  }
}

function checkLength2(elem) {
  if (elem.value > 4) {
    alert('Max value is 4')
    elem.value = '';
  }
}

function readValue() {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f1f1f1">
  <h2 align="center"><u>Password policy setting page</u></h2>
  <div class="container" align="center">
    <form id="myForm" align="center">
      Expiry <br> <input type="range" name="ExpiryRange" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.ExpiryInput.value=this.value" />
      <span class='number-wrapper'>
              <input type="number" name="ExpiryInput" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.ExpiryRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" />
            </span><br> Min.Length
      <br><input type="range" name="MinlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenInput.value=this.value" />
      <input type="number" name="MinlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="8" oninput="this.form.MinlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br> Max.Length
      <br><input type="range" name="MaxlenRange" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenInput.value=this.value" />
      <input type="number" name="MaxlenInput" min="0" max="100" value="60" oninput="this.form.MaxlenRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength1(this)" /><br> Lowercase Letter<br><input type="range" name="LCRange" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.LCInput.value=this.value"
      />
      <input type="number" name="LCInput" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.LCRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br> Uppercase Letter<br><input type="range" name="UCRange" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.UCInput.value=this.value"
      />
      <input type="number" name="UCInput" min="0" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.UCRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br> Digit
      <br><input type="range" name="DRange" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.DInput.value=this.value" />
      <input type="number" name="DInput" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.DRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br> Symbol
      <br><input type="range" name="SRange" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.SInput.value=this.value" />
      <input type="number" name="SInput" min="1" max="4" value="1" oninput="this.form.SRange.value=this.value" onkeyup="checkLength2(this)" /><br>
      <br><br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div align="center">
    <input type="Submit" align="center" onclick="alert('Success!!!')">
    <input id="reset" onclick="resetFunc()" type="button" value="Reset">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can add runnable code by pressing ctrl+M or by pressing the button that looks like `<>` :)

Comment: It seems odd to have `alert('Max value is 4')` when you set the value in the HTML to 8.